# 'undefined' return in Google WebApps w/ Instagram iOS Browser

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, instagram

I'm having an issue on opening my Google WebApps with Instagram iOS Browser. Code below shows a simple example

```
function doGet(e) {

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('This Page works!');

}
```

It works on all browsers I've tested except iOS Instagram browser. Attached is the screenshot of the error.

I've also tried to change HtmlService to ContentService and it worked, so I'm guessing it's something with HtmlService.

```
function doGet(e) {

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("TESTE!");

}
```

If anyone has any idea how to solve this, I'd appreciate. Thanks

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyGNC.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDPUy.jpg)